# How do I install and use OTF fonts?

Tags: fonts, miktex

The French Ministry of Education has made writing fonts available to teachers in OTF format.

The provided files allow to install them on the Windows operating system (for Mac, I don't know).

These fonts are here: http://eduscol.education.fr/cid72979/polices-de-caracteres-cursives-pour-l-enseignement-de-l-ecriture.html

- Is it possible to install them on a MikTeX distribution?
- And if so how?
- Is it possible to use it with LaTeX? with PDFLaTeX?
- If not, is there another way to use them on TeX derivative systems?

Comment: If they are OTF, install it using your OS installation options. Then use XeLaTeX or LuaLaTeX and `fontspec`.

Comment: Texnician is correct. Use the fontspec package. Be sure to read its documentation. Use utf-8 exclusively. Compile using lualatex or xetex. You do not need to know Lua. If the Open Type fonts have feature sets, you will be able to use them. I believe that the fonts do not need to be installed "in MikTeX". Simply install in Windows, like any ordinary font.

Comment: Btw, this https://www.tug.org/levels.html may be useful for better understanding

Comment: "fontools" is one of a nice tool help to use the OTF fonts in MikTeX, it has nice documentation too...

Comment: @MadyYuvi This tool does not have a real user manual, can you indicate how to use it in this case?

Comment: For Mac users, go to the Finder, hit Command-Shift-G, enter `~/Library/Fonts`, copy the OTF fonts into the Fonts folder. Restart your Mac and then, as noted by @TeXnician above, use XeLaTeX or LuaLaTeX and `fontspec`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem you have has nothing to do with the specific LaTeX distribution that you use. The OTF fonts, once installed, can be used by any software which uses fonts (such as, say, Microsoft Word). An explanation on how to install them can be seen [here](https://www.fontspring.com/support/installing/how-do-i-install-fonts-on-my-windows-pc).

Once the fonts are installed, you can use them using XeLaTeX. For instance, an OTF font that I have on my computers is called `DTLUnicoST`. When I want to use it as the main text font in a XeLaTeX document, I put the line `\setmainfont[Mapping=tex-text-ms]{DTLUnicoST}`in the preamble of that document. Be sure to load one of the packages `fontspec`or `xltxtra`.

---

Here's an example:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\setmainfont[Mapping=tex-text-ms]{Cambria}
\begin{document}
Hello World!
\end{document}
```

Note the encoding of the LaTeX file must be Unicode.

Comment: @JoséCarlosSantos I never used XeLaTeX. Can you give an ECM indicating the minimum preamble for XeLaTeX?

Comment: @AndréC I've edited my answer.

Comment: @JoséCarlosSantos All right, this works with the font distributed by the French National Education Department by writing `\setmainfont[Mapping=tex-text-ms]{EcritureA-Italique}`.
But what is the `[Mapping=tex-text-ms]` option for?

Comment: @AndréC I really don't know. I was just following a suggestion that I got [here](http://tug.org/pipermail/xetex/2010-June/016990.html).